# Random spaces appear between elements in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a RPG game and had stuck on map creation.

My map is made like that (to get the deal about position):

```
    mapTile.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x * (texture.width), y * (texture.height) , 0);
```

"mapTile" is a fresh generated texture (NGUI addChild). 
"texture" is a prefab which these tiles are generated from (prefab has no texture, just height/width).

I have made a web-based map editor, so this is what I see there (and what i expect to see in the game):
[image: http://imgur.com/NvcVKsX]

Unfortunately, in the game testing the map contains some mysterious changes like:
[image: http://imgur.com/yta3a47]

All the icons have no such things what you see in the photo below.

Any solution for this? If you need more info, just say.
Thanks.

Comment: Fixed. All I had to do was to change resource's "Wrap mode" to "Clamp".

Comment: You should post that as your answer. Maybe upload a picture of it too. I will gladly up-vote.

Comment: @FunctionR thank you for noticing, posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found a solution for this mysterious bug.
Somehow when my icons are 32x32 and prefab is 32x32 also, it repeats the icon, so it becomes like 31px + 1px repeat (it doesn't happen with higher resolution objects). 
As you can see in the picture below - select all the icons and set "Wrap Mode" to "Clamp". No more problems.
[image: tiles fix]
[image: fixed]

Comment: Very nice. Good luck on the game!